# Check if SQL statement actually ran

Tags: php, mysql

I am posting this in order to see if someone could help me to solve this little problem. Right now I have this code:

```
visible $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' AND level >249 AND power>0 LIMIT 1";
```

What I want to do is that if the query actually runs, print `Correct`, otherwise, `Error`.

What I tried:

```
visible       $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' AND level >249 AND power>0 LIMIT 1";
              $updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
              if($sqlUpdate==1) {

              }
              else { echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>'; }

            }
            else {
              echo'<p class="as">Error .</p>';
            }
```

But that does not work.

Comment: What does `visible` do? I haven't come across that before.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `$updatePos`?

Comment: Your script is probably vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_affected_rows()` which returns the number of affected rows on success, *and -1 if the last query failed*.

```
$chrVal = $_GET['char'];
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user SET level = '1' WHERE id = '$chrVal' AND level > 249 AND power > 0 LIMIT 1";
$updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
if(mysql_affected_rows() >= 1) 
{ 
    echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>';
}
else
{
    echo'<p class="as">Error .</p>';
}
```

- [mysql_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know whether row updated or not. try `mysql_affected_rows()`

[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

```
$char = mysql_escape_string($_GET['char']);
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='" . $char . "' AND level >249 AND power>0 LIMIT 1";
$updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
$affRows = mysql_affected_rows();
if ($affRows) {
  echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>';
} else {
  echo'<p class="as">Error .</p>';
}
```

also use `mysql_escape_string` to avoid sql injections :)

Answer (score 1):

If condition should check the $updatePos. If it comes out to be true then it is correct else it will give you error.

you can check an example from here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

change your variable name $sqlUpdate to $updatePos

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' AND level >249 AND power>0 LIMIT 1";
                  $updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
                  if($updatePos==1) {

                  }
                  else { echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>'; }

                }
                else {
                  echo'<p class="as">Error .</p>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following.

```
 if( $updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate))
 {
 echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>';     
 }
 else
 {
 echo'<p class="as">Error.</p>';     
 }
```

if the query is wrong, it will return error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' AND level >249 AND power>0 LIMIT 1";
              $updatePos = mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
              if($updatePos==1) {

              }
              else { echo'<p class="as">Correct.</p>'; }

            }
            else {
              echo'<p class="as">Error .</p>';
            }
```

You can also check it mysql_num_rows();

Like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)